# Why does Meta allow posts that are not questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

I have searched to see if there was any post about this but the only thing I could find was [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44189/391772) explaining what Meta is, and it still suggests that Meta is supposed to be used for asking questions, not advertising new features or announcing new community managers.

For example, how is [*this*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313086/391772) a question?

Why should someone get 1460 (292*5) points for "asking" it?

We then have people getting 530 (53*10) points just for saying congratulations and nothing else:

> [image]

Furthermore, and perhaps of most importance, why do we only let these free points for people saying things like "congratulations" go to people that already have 10 points reputation (see image below)?

> [image]

Comment: Also see this Help Center page: [What's Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog: You have ***three times*** posted a link to a question that was already linked in the first line of my question, in my original version. I find that to be very unwelcoming, like you want to send me away. Where in that "duplicate" question is the answer to "why do we only let these free points for people saying things like "congratulations" go to people that already have 10 points reputation (see image below)?"

Comment: In theory all that "reputation" could be eliminated if those posts get marked as community wiki, if that is your biggest concern.

Comment: @rene, why don't we do that then? It is not my biggest concern though. Isn't this supposed to be a place where we ask questions? Shouldn't announcements go somewhere else?

Comment: They don't have another platform that is so closely tied to the community. Why should they go somewhere else?

Comment: But the blog is focused on the non-se community. That said: there are ideas on adding new type of posttypes that address your concerns on announcements not being questions. Allow for 6 to 8 weeks to see these changes materialize.

Comment: There's a typo in the text. It should be *For example, how is this an [***answer***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313086/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-599-catherine-kuck-aka-catija/313092#313092)? The newly appointed manager wrote a fairly lengthy piece, so the upvotes is a quick simple way to say "Well done. We're pleased for you" Likewise the downvotes are there to say "We are not pleased". Are you going to begrudge  a new employee getting "upvotes"? However, I agree that answers basically saying  "congratulations" should not benefit.

Comment: @user1271772 If you don't like the dupe perhaps you should [edit] your question and make the title match the contents. The dupe answers the question title ...

Comment: First of all, I've only posted two links. Second of all, neither of the links I posted go to any posts you've linked.

Comment: FWIW, we even have [tag:announcements] tag on MSE...

Comment: @Shadow: Can you please not do that? You know that this is not a Dupe, and all you had to do was wait for 1 more person to vote.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog how does the original question answer this post? Could you please direct me to the relevant excerpts that explains users, and managers can also use meta for announcements? Thanks.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There is sort of an explanation in the "Tone" section, but I think it should have more info. Note that I also linked to the help center page "What's Meta?" in a subsequent comment.

Comment: @Shadow the Welcoming Wizard how does the original question answer this post? Could you please direct me to the relevant excerpts that explains users, and managers can also use meta for announcements? Thanks.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog *…it should be…* but it's not. Ergo this post is *not* a duplicate. At least one of the answers on the older post should have included that excerpt  "What's Meta?" The "tone" section says, and I quote, "**…
Meta has a reputation for being more... relaxed than the other Stack Exchange sites. Jokes and non-serious posts that would be swiftly deleted on the other sites have been welcomed here in the past and are sometimes still tolerated today, though not to the degree that they were before.**…" It still doesn't answer *this* question

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Why have they rolled back my edit that was accepted by the community? https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/47634/revisions

Comment: You have to ask that question to @rene

Comment: @user1271772 I think he rolled it back because links there are only intended to be direct links to that specific question's answers, not to other questions. As the post was Community Wiki, it wasn't approved by other users, but directly applied immediately on your making it, so there's no way to "reject" it.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog: so you are saying that the answer to my question is NOT in there? Then why did you vote to close my question as a duplicate? I do not understand why you are allowed to participate in Meta.

Comment: The close reason shown in the box is only there because someone used their binding vote to close this as a duplicate. Other voters may not have necessarily picked the same reason. I myself think that the question is off-topic because it's completely answered in the help center article.

Comment: Despite that, I'll be honest with you: I've been at odds with the community for the same reason many times, and I was once publicly cast out for voting to close a "thanks" post here on meta. I was among those who upvoted your question. I was just trying to fit in with the community's stance because I do generally uphold it even when I disagree with it.

Comment: Then what is on topic @SonictheInclusiveWerehog? Announcements about new employees? That's not even a question about stack exchange. It does not fall under the reasons for Meta. It should be posted in a blog and advertised in chat. How could you possibly say that my question is off-topic? And honestly I think you're changing your mind wen you say "off-topic" because originally you voted to close as "duplicate" not as "off-topic". Those are 2 separate close reasons. Thanks for upvoting, but voting to close did not help, it just reassured people who were having second thoughts about driving my

Comment: rep to zero for being a new user trying to ask a good question. Where is the answer to "why do we only let these free points for people saying things like "congratulations" go to people that already have 10 points reputation (see image below)?"  ?? If you cannot answer that question, please re-open the question. Is "why do we only let these free points for people saying things like "congratulations" go to people that already have 10 points reputation (see image below)?" off topic ?

Comment: I have to agree here that I don't see how this question is answered in the duplicate. It might have other related and/or possible duplicates but closing it against the FAQ doesn't address the specific question asked here. Re-opened for that reason.

Comment: I've rolled-back that edit you made on the FAQ question because that post only linked to answers on that specific post and if it does link to other posts, at least they should be [tag:faq-proposed] while they are being edit/curated to be [tag:faq] ready. This question is far from that and therefor not appropriate to be considered a good FAQ candidate. It could become one but let's not rush it.

Comment: @rene: thank you for re-opening, and letting me know the explanation about FAQs. The re-opening has come far after I've already been swarmed with over 14 negative votes, even quicker than in the moderator reform question, even though this time I wasn't even complaining about moderators, just asking why something I find strange seems to be acceptable here. It was the same problem that time, a huge rush to immediately close the question as dupe, when in fact the dupe link about "what recourse I have" was irrelevant, I was just asking about changing the moderators periodically.

Comment: So why are people here so unwelcoming? Closing things as dupes without even waiting for 5 votes? Without giving enough time for feedback? The people voting to close might not have even earned their reputation, they might have just written "Congratulations!" on some question that shouldn't even be a question. Or they announced that they hired someone new, and got a bunch of reputation for doing that. Then from their 105k reputation they can afford to downvote every single question on Meta without losing any privileges. I can't downvote some of the answers because my reputation is still precious

Comment: I'm not able to do some mind reading for the down voters but I can imagine the tone of voice of your question might not be received well. It sounds rather accusatory and/or jealous for the gained reputation. Some users might find that not useful to discuss. Intentional or not, that same tone speaks from some of your comments.

Comment: Actually I had 2 upvotes and 0 downvotes, then I got some erroneous defamatory comments saying that I should look at some other Meta question, which I already posted a link to in my original question. Then I started getting close votes, and then the down votes came. But in any case, I'm not asking for mind reading, what I'm asking is, don't you think people like yourself should be punished for closing questions without thinking?

Comment: You should be assuming good faith for actions taken.  Just because you disagree with them doesn't mean the actions were, "without thinking".  As soon as you start throwing around ideas like punishment for actions you disagree with, you're going to see a lot of backlash.  Users have earned those privileges; the system trusts them to use them properly.  Argue if you disagree, but don't assume you're right.

Comment: @fbueckert: they earned the reputation by writing "congratulations" on people's posts and getting 56 upvotes for that. Or by announcing that they hired a new employee and getting hundreds of upvotes for that. Reputation on Meta is corrupt. And also, I strongly believe that not much thought was put into the close votes.

Comment: Well, if you won't assume good faith, then it's on you to bring something more to the table than your belief.  Show us proof.  Your disagreement with it isn't proof.  When you start tossing around charged words like, "corrupt", you're signalling you're not at all receptive to an actual debate, so less people will be interested in engaging, and will just downvote and move on.

Comment: @fbueckert: I don't have time to argue with you. You don't seem to know what you're talking about. You high-rep Meta users always ask for "proof". It's like you have no respect for people's time. It is extremely obvious that Meta is corrupt. The employees post junk and it doesn't get deleted. They post un-intelligent answers like "they downvoted because they lost their keys" rather than putting throught into it. Sarcastic answers are against the CoC but because they're employees it's okay. It is super corrupt and you know it. You are just being annoying by asking me for "proof".

Comment: No, we ask for proof so we have something tangible to actually discuss.  Your refusal to provide any, and further hostility against discussing this shows this is a losing proposition.  I'm not saying Meta is perfect in any sense; it has it's warts.  But it's not corrupt. Not by a long shot whatsoever.  You need to accept that to have a good reception here.  But I'm done.  Good day.

Comment: @fbueckert, what proof do you have that it is not corrupt? And why do i NEED to accept it ?

Comment: A pity you forgot the time when I defended and upvoted your question!

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I remembered it very vividly! That's why I was surprised when you deleted everything. For what it's worth, thank you for defending and upvoting my question. More recently I found out from the chemistry stack exchange that moderators can automatically convert an answer into a comment. I think the "congratulations !!!!" should be converted to a comment, but it turns out there is no point in spending time trying to improve Meta (at least it seems that way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Catija has been a great addition to the ranks of the Community Managers, and I welcomed the announcement of that appointment here on Meta Stack Exchange.

However, with the announcement being made in the area normally used for questions (like it was), I would have preferred to see it tagged permanently with [announcements](/questions/tagged/announcements) (like it was) and for a few weeks with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) (like it was), ***and locked at the outset so that no answers or comments could be posted***.

Instead of writing this near the end of the announcement:

> Please join us in congratulating Cat in her new role! Questions about
>   the stuff she's going to be working on, or questions in general?

I think it would have been better to write:

> For any questions about the stuff Cat's going to be working on, or
>   questions in general, as always, please post a new question here on
>   Meta SE.

Comment: Why is it okay to put the announcement as a "question" in Meta, rather than in a Blog? Can I use meta to advertise as well? Or to make announcements? Why can employees do it but not regular citizens? The blog is the normal way to make announcements isn't it?

Comment: I'm comfortable with SO choosing whether to use a blog post or Meta SE "question" to make an announcement like this.  I don't think that should open the door for any of us to do it.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [reputation limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), so users can only get 200 reputation per day (some exceptions apply). The quoted reputation gained for these questions and answers will not be accurate.

Protection doesn't happen immediately, if something was protected by Community it means that a number of answers have already been posted (29 in this case). Low reputation users could have got the reputation if they'd got in quickly enough.

Reputation on Meta is slightly meaingless anyways... it's here just because this isn't technically a meta site. It's imaginary internet points on a site about the interaction with sites where you gain imaginery internet points. If you participate regularly the reputation will come, whether or not you manage to get the one highly upvoted *"Congratulations!!!"* answer.

---

Whether Meta should be used for announcements is quite a contentious issue, [especially announcements that are percieved to be social](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114020/please-do-not-use-stack-overflow-to-promote-social-causes). Generally "questions" about new staff members are left alone, but announcements of new products are often closed multiple times. [Meta Stack Overflow is perhaps even harsher](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/307513/revisions).

Whatever your personal opinion, Stack Overflow (the company) has decided to use their platform for announcements. This means that the meta sites throughout the network (but especially Meta Stack Exchange) *are* used for announcements.

Until Stack Overflow changes their mind announcements will continue to be posted and no extant answer by a regular user will change this fact. The answer should maybe be edited to reflect that announcements might be posted.

Comment: Can you please remove the link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114020/please-do-not-use-stack-overflow-to-promote-social-causes because it is about political statements, not about social announcements?

Comment: I used the word _"social"_ because that is the word in the title @user1271772. Whether or those announcements are political or not is _extremely_ contentious. They are always social (of or relating to society), whether or not you also believe they're policitical so I'd prefer to leave the wording used in the original question.

Comment: okay. The example in my question is about "announcements" of new staff members, and the example in your link is completely different. The fact that your thing is a contentious issue doesn't have much to do with my question, so I edited it.

Comment: Please fix your user name. It is not backwards, it is upside down and backwards ;)

Comment: You're [not the first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180825/are-there-any-chat-rules-on-stack-overflow#comment548962_180827) to [make that point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161174/how-can-i-see-how-many-edits-left-for-archaeologist-badge#comment755453_161175) @David :-).

Comment: So fix it. Rotated != Backwards.

Answer (score 4):

#### It still suggests that Meta is supposed to be used for asking questions, not advertising new features or announcing new community managers.

The question references the following answer [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying/44189#44189)

That answer explicitly states:

> Meta Stack Exchange is a special place for suggestions, bugs, support questions, and discussion about the Stack Exchange sites.

Suggestions, bug reports and discussion  are not (explicit) questions. So clearly the site is **not** limited to only asking questions.

That makes "advertising new features or announcing new community managers." on topic.

Answer (score 4):

A tool is whatever you need it to be. My dad used to hammer in nails with a pestle for years until we got multiple hammers and insisted he use it.

While traditionally, announcements were made over the blog, it's a bit of a clunky tool at the current point, and to a big extent is more aimed at an external audience than the core user base.

On the other hand, there's this old, almost forgotten diagram:

[image: Intersection of Wiki, Digg/Reddit, Forum, and Blog]

...which once resided in the tour page - and that really does reflect meta well - least for many of us, it acts as a community built repository of knowledge (aka a wiki). It's a place for announcements, and acts almost as a secondary blog. While I'd bristle at calling it a forum in the modern sense - it is a place for discussion. Not sure about these Digg/Reddit things.

In a sense, folks at SE found that the 20-lb sledgehammer worked less well for their needs here than one of these:

[image]
<sub>[By Agolz12 - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=38908865)</sub>

It's a multi-purpose tool that does many things. It might not be the best tool for driving in stakes but... that's not what we always need.

So meta *is used* by Stack Overflow in this way since it's the most efficient way to get information through to the broader Stack Exchange Userbase.

Comment: The diagram can still be accessed by typing in the Konami code on the tour page.

Comment: @Journeyman Greek: It is unfair that people would get reputation for such things though. Can we move these to Community Wiki?

Comment: I suppose a mod/CM could do that. Or individual users. Admittedly it did not cross my mind the last time I posted one of those. I just wanted to be a good sport, and express my happiness. I guess SE is fine with a little *appropriate* fun?

Answer (score 3):

Why Stack Overflow is allowed to post that kind of questions is explained in the help center and the FAQ link found by @Sonic, and in @ben's answer. Let me focus on

> Furthermore, and perhaps of most importance, why do we only let these free points for people saying things like "congratulations" go to people that already have 10 points reputation (see image below)?

On that particular post, there are a few answers which have been deleted:

[image]

Just being able to post the umpteenth variation of 'Congratulations' is not a guarantee for free reputation. In general, on these kind of questions, you have to be quick (the ['fastest gun in the west'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18014/295232)), which means you have to be either very lucky or to be here all the time. Guess what, the same users who are here all the time are the ones which already have a lot of reputation. This holds true for every Stack Exchange site in the network, including Meta.

Comment: What about the other 18 answers all basically saying "congratulations"? A case of jumping on the bandwagon to earn easy rep, or a genuine expression of good will?

Comment: I don't know, I can't read users' minds :)

Comment: In the meantime another answer hit the dust. I just saw it vanish. Unfortunately, I don't have 10K rep on this site.

Comment: Complete text was [_"Congratulations ! looking forward to see your lead"_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/59982) @Mari-LouA with a score of -5 - it's the type of answer that'd have normally been deleted at the time.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I think it also had two upvotes, maybe they gained another DV when this question was posted. In any case, most of the positive messages could have been summed up in one or two posts. Few users broke the mold and when they did they were castigated heavily until they felt compelled to completely rewrite their post.

Comment: Two upvotes, seven downvotes. I voted to delete it because it does not add any value; that can be said of most answers there, but I can't vote to delete those.

Comment: You can DV them tho... :P

Comment: Maybe I can, maybe I already did it ...