# Is the chatroom to be used for topic related chatting or not?

Tags: discussion, chat, answers, off-topic, android

I found a chat section in Stack Overflow. Is it to be used for simply chatting or a particular topic?

For example, if Android is the name of the chat room, is there only Android-related chat allowed?

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat

Comment: Yes, but what is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any chat rules on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180825/are-there-any-chat-rules-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each and every chat room has their own rules. Generally, they are displayed in the top right corner.

[image]

[image]

There are also some rooms that help the user to moderate sites like:

[image]

[image]

So, before participating, read their rules and FAQs; these should give you an idea what the room is about.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the Android room shown in your screenshot is in gallery mode so you can only talk there on invitation, aka if you have been given write-access by an Room Owner. Additionally you need chat privileges which come at 20 rep, which the OP doesn't have yet anywhere